# More clear and visual distinction between .org and .com needed?

Tags: feature-request

Pretty much every .com question gets confused to be about .org by someone. At best it is explicitly said in question (far from always from start), but even then it is easy to overlook.

Maybe questions should have some clearly identifying marks to make them easier to distinguish? Like some badge in the corner somewhere?

I think this is somewhat unique situation because it is same **platform** but very different **products** with very close naming and terminology on top. We do not get a lot of .com questions for now, but when we expand beyond .org techies as audience it can become a flood fast.

Answer (score 2):

Would using tags more consistently help?  We have tags for both `wordpress.com` and `wordpress.org`, but we don't really assign them that much.

Comment: Tags are nice, but as for me they are not something you look at first or something very visible. While tags are useful for organization, browsing, search and such I think com/org distinction doesn't really fall under them.

Comment: I also think this is something for the tags, but then only the exception: `[wordpress.com]`. I would not add an extra UI indication for all users, but you can always do this for yourself with a Greasemonkey script.

Answer (score 2):

I was a strong proponent for answering WordPress.com questions when WordPress Answers started, but now that we've lived with it for a while I would happily vote to refocus the site to be for answers about Self-Hosted only.  We are much more technical here than regular WordPress support and our best answers usually involve code.

I should probably ask another question with a new title to debate this?

-Mike